# ModuleNotFoundError in Spyder

Tags: package, spyder, biopython

I tried to import the biopython package in Spyder and got the error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'biopython'
```

although biopython is installed.

I also checked the PYTHONPATH: there is a path set into the directory where the packages are stored.

Can somebody help? Did I miss something? Thanks for your help!

Comment: How did you install Spyder and how did you install biopython? What happens if you start Python from the command line and try `import biopython` there?

Comment: I used the anaconda navigator to install spyder. Biopyhton I installed with the pip install command. I tried to import biopython from the command line but I got the same error message. I think that I found the problem: it seems that the biopython folder doesn't include the package itself but I found other folders (e.g. Bio, BioSQL) that were installed together with biopython and they include some python scripts. The folder from biopython ("biopython-1.7.1.dist-info") is more or less empty (some text files). Maybe the command pip install is the wrong (or another) way for installing biopython.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please see the second part of [our video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) to understand how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Anaconda, it's best to install all the packages you want from Anaconda if possible. You can check if a package is available with (e.g.):

```
conda search biopython
```

When I try that command it shows that biopython is available, so assuming you have access to the standard conda channels you should be able to get it this way.

Assuming you haven't already created a conda environment to work with, start by creating a new one with the packages you want to use:

```
conda create -n myenvname spyder biopython
```

where `myenvname` is the name you want to give the environment - call it whatever you like. If you want to use other packages as well, add their names to the end of this command. Then once the env is completed, activate it:

```
activate myenvname
```

or if this doesn't work, on Mac or Linux:

```
source activate myenvname
```

and start Spyder in this environment:

```
spyder
```

Each time you want to use this environment in future you will need to `activate` it first. You may also be able to do some of these tasks through the Anaconda Navigator or via Start menu shortcuts but the command line version will always work.

If there's a package you want that isn't available from conda but is available via pip, just use the `pip` command **after** creating and activating the environment.

Comment: What if the package is not available? Or what if package is listed (confirmed by conda list command) and Spyder can't see it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anaconda, a solution could be

```
conda install -c main biopython
```

following https://anaconda.org/main/biopython.

The official repository page helped me when I got your error message because numpy was not in place.